# How do i pass variable from multiples pages to one page flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my flutter project i have many pages. I want to pass variables from different pages(named destination,departure,date,time etc) to one page (named homePage).How do i get many variables from different pages to one page and construct them ?

Comment: Can you share your code from where you want to navigate?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can you redux for your flow and data management.
   you can follow this [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wj216eSBBWs)
2. You can you shared_preferences to get data over multiple screens.

Add following code in your .yaml file.
dependencies:

```
    flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
```

Example Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Saving data'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Read'),
              onPressed: () {
                _read();
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Save'),
              onPressed: () {
                _save();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // Replace these two methods in the examples that follow

  _read() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'my_int_key';
    final value = prefs.getInt(key) ?? 0;
    print('read: $value');
  }

  _save() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'my_int_key';
    final value = 42;
    prefs.setInt(key, value);
    print('saved $value');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea #1
One possible way is to store them in a singleton so you can access them everywhere inside your app.

You can update the values inside the singleton and then later access them in your "homepage".

Package to use : https://pub.dev/packages/global_configuration

Idea #2
Use a database to store the data and access them in your "homepage".

Package to use : 
https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Idea #3
Store the data inside the shared preferences and access them in your "homepage".

Package to use :
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Idea #2 and #3 are persistent, that means the data is available after the app is closed and started again at any other time.

Idea #1 is not persistent and the data is lost when the app is closed.

So the main idea is to store the data somewhere and access them later.

Answer (score 0):

Include a state management library in your app. State management libraries allow you to separate business logic from UI and such state can also be accessed from any part of the app.
Official flutter website lists a few approaches to state management, you can pick one which suits you best. See [state management approaches](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).